# Unit test for controller in MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have following in my controller file:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ClientGroupIndexViewModel()
    {
        AddScanUrl = Url.RouteUrl<ClientGroupsController>(c => c.CreateNewScan(null, null)),
        //other similar stuff
    };

    return View("ClientGroupsIndex", model);
}


public JsonResult CreateNewScan(ClientGroup clientGroup, Version version)
{
    //do something
    return Json(new{Message = "created new scan", Success = true});
}
```

I've to write Unit test case for **CreateNewScan**. How can this be done (preferably using built-in testing framework in VS)? Any pointers in this regard appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8563657/2436549

Comment: Using the link @Zafar posted, you might want to check the Success value in your test.

Comment: @Darek Trying to take help of the answer in the posted link but I'm a total newbie and couldn't understand much. Any further help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Testing MVC Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562888/unit-testing-mvc-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although for some reason on my workstation throws an error.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateNewScan()
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        ClientGroup clientGroup = new ClientGroup(){ 
            //some property initializers
        };
        JsonResult result = controller.CreateNewScan(clientGroup, new Version(1, 0));
        dynamic data = result.Data;
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Success);
    }
```

Please try and let me know. My PC has been acting up recently.

**UPDATE**

The PC was "acting up" because [when using dynamic type, you must allow the test project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274235/564092) to see the internals of your web application. So in your AssemblyInfo.cs of the web application, make sure you add this line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("WebApplication1.Tests")]
```

where `WebApplication1.Tests` is the assembly name of your test project.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Sorry if this is a stupid question but it also asks for [UrlToTest()]. I know that there are some url routing here. The one I see in the browser is not acceptable. How do I fnd right URL to test?

Comment: Do you mean how to test Index()?

Comment: Never mind, was a stupid question anyway. This works :) Thanks a lot.